# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Indicator not working with Angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Here Is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" *ngFor="let li of images; let i = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [ngClass]="i == 0 ? 'active':''"></li>
        </ol>  
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div *ngFor="let image of images; let k = index" [ngClass]="k == 0 ? 'carousel-item active':'carousel-item'">
          <img class="d-block w-100" [src]=image.path [alt]=image.alt>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code seems to be correct. I have tried multiple solutions but none seems to be working.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: it's better to use ng-bootstrap with has a simpler solution for carousel . https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Comment: Of it won't work. Nothing that requires JS in bootstrap works :) Just use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples or build separate components that initialize bootstrap function in afterViewInit.

Comment: Do you see but are unable to click on the indicators?

Comment: yes I can see the indicator but unable to click

Comment: can you solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes i got it working. I forgot to include bootstrap.js and jquery

Answer (score -1):

Carousel is working perfect in angular 7

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q9o6zyjr0w

if you any doubt you can comment below.

Answer (score -2):

Your ngClass is worng. This way work in AngularJs, but not in Angular 7.
You need to use this way: [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}".